# Roots of polynomial depend continuously on coefficents

Tags: polynomials

I'm not sure why this statement is true. For example, consider the polynomial $ax^2+x-1$. The only root of $x-1$ is $x=1$. But the roots of $ax^2+x-1$ are $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4a}}{2a}$, and $\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+4a}}{2a}\not\to1$ as $a\to 0^+$, so wouldn't this be a counterexample?

Comment: Actually if you take the positive square root the limit is $1$.

Comment: Right, I know the positive root would have limit one, but what about the negative root? That limit would be $-\infty$. The way I'm interpreting the statement is, "if $x_a$ is any root of $ax^2+x-1$, then $\text{lim}_{a\to 0}x_a$ is a root of $x-1$

Comment: Using Vieta's formula you can find a mapping from the roots to the coefficients, and then apply the inverse mapping theorem if applicable

Comment: @Tim I think that probably only works if the degree doesn't change. It's asking too much for it to still be true true if it does.

Comment: Think of it this way: the negative root function is continuous, but its domain doesn't include $a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

When $a$ is very small, it is natural to see that the polynomial $ax^2+x-1\approx x-1$ and so 1 is an approximate root. But as $a$ is just very small but is still non-zero, if we take a big enough $x$, $ax^2$ will not be that small and both $ax^2$ and $1-x$ are not close to $0$ but they have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good example. There are two roots. As $a$ gets small, one root goes to $1$ and the other to infinity. Both roots are continuous in $a$. The infinity root is like $1/a$. This function is continuous from the right. It is undefined at zero and the limit from the left is minus infinity and from the right is plus infinity. This whole situation arises because at $a=0$ the polynomial drops in degree by one. The theorem holds only if the number of roots stays constant. Otherwise, as in this case, there are some anomalous results.